# Glassfish 5 HttpServletRequest.getServerName() not returning server from client request

Tags: java, redirect, servlets, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I'm currently migrating my enterprise Java Application from Java 7 to Java 8, from Java EE 6 to Java EE 8 and Glassfish 3.1.2.2 to Glassfish 5.0. Thereby I face issues with the redirects in Servlets.

The application is running in a docker container on Docker for Mac in docker compose environment. When I try to access the application with e.g. `https://localhost:58181/myapp/secure` the application will check for a valid authentication and as the user is not authenticated the application should redirect to `https://localhost:58181/myapp/public/login`.

This worked fine within Glassfish 3.1.2.2 but with Glassfish 5.0 the redirect is going to `https://mayapp:8181/myapp/public/login` whereas myapp is the docker host name and 8181 is the port Glassfish which is exposed to the outside as 58181. So it is using the docker hostname and port instead of the hostname and port of the request.

In the application the redirect is triggered with:

```
httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/myapp/public/login");
```

I had a deeper look into this issue. Compared to Glassfish 3.1.2.2 `httpServletRequest.getServerName()` returns `myapp` instead of `localhost` and the same is the case for `httpServletRequest.getServerPort()` (8181 vs. 58181). These methods a called within `httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(...)` to setup the complete redirect URL.

I also created a small project (https://github.com/gessnerfl/glassfish-servlet-test) which proofs that this changed with Glassfish 5.0. The project just contains a small servlet which renders some details from the HttpServletRequest:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/test")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet{
   @Override
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
       Writer writer = resp.getWriter();
       writer.append("Request URL: "+req.getRequestURL().toString()+"\n");
       writer.append("Request URI: "+req.getRequestURI()+"\n");
       writer.append("Server Name: "+req.getServerName()+"\n");
       writer.append("Server Port: "+req.getServerPort()+"\n");
       writer.append("Local Name: "+req.getLocalName()+"\n");
       writer.append("Local Port: "+req.getLocalPort()+"\n");
       writer.append("Remote Host: "+req.getRemoteHost()+"\n");
       writer.append("Remote Port: "+req.getRemotePort());
       writer.flush();
   }
}
```

With Glassfish 3.1.2.2 (Java 7) and Glassfish 4.1.2 (Java 7 and Java 8) the result is (port numbers and the local/remote name differ due to the docker setup but that does not matter in this case):

```
Request URL: https://localhost:38181/test-servlet/test
Request URI: /test-servlet/test
Server Name: localhost
Server Port: 38181
Local Name: 7a786606bfac
Local Port: 8181
Remote Host: 172.19.0.1
Remote Port: 40136
```

With Glassfish 5.0 this changes to:

```
Request URL: https://3eb4cbbf3a08:8181/test-servlet/test
Request URI: /test-servlet/test
Server Name: 3eb4cbbf3a08
Server Port: 8181
Local Name: 3eb4cbbf3a08
Local Port: 8181
Remote Host: 172.19.0.1
Remote Port: 52318
```

As you can see the request URL as well as the server name and port changed to the same as the local name.

Is the new behaviour correct? Is it a change in the servlet specification (did not found anything related to this)?

I know that as an alternative I could get the request host from the HTTP Header `HOST`. But as this is part of the Java EE standard I would not have expected such a change.

Comment: WIth my further investigations this looks more like a change in Glassfish. so I opened an issue for the Glassfish project - https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/22390.

Comment: Can you see if the HTTP header `X-Forwarded-For` exists now?  This is the standard that [Apache httpd uses](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers) and I have seen it used elsewhere.

Comment: I changed the test servlet slightly to also render the headers but as expected it does not include X-Forwarded-For header. There is not proxy in between. I directly access the Glassfish server. 
The artefact is compiled individually for each Java and Java EE version. But the implementation is the same.
Also the Glassfish domain.xml is the default configuration without modification.

Comment: Sorry - now that I re-read your post I misunderstood.  Sorry for the bother.

Comment: @FlorianGeßner Good day. Were you able to solve this issue? Not using Glassfish but a simple SpringBoot in a docker container project. When I try submit my request from react to springboot, the `HttpServletRequest request`'s servername, changes to docker's container name while running via API(postman, insomia), it is using localhost.

Comment: my SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77365258/mvcuricomponentsbuilder-uses-the-container-name-for-servername-instead-of-localh