# MvcUriComponentsBuilder uses the container name for servername instead of localhost issue

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, docker, spring-mvc

I have a Docker container for React and SpringBoot. In springboot server, I am able to generate a `confirmationURL` using the `MvcUriComponentsBuilder`. It is based on [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77277076/13933721). What this do is generate a URL based on the Controller and Method Name with parameters. However when I submit a POST request from React to Springboot, the URL changes to the Spring Boot's container name instead of localhost.

**TLDR**:

1. submit via postman generates the correct url format.
2. submit via react servername changes to container_name

**Note**: The `HttpServletRequest` also uses the container_name instead of localhost.

Check via: `request.getServerName();`

--Code Start--

**Docker Compose**

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  client:
    container_name: springbootapp-client
    # restart: always
    build: ./docker/client
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./client:/var/www/client:cached
      - ./docker/client/entrypoint.sh:/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh:cached

  server:
    container_name: springbootapp-server
    # restart: always
    build: ./docker
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "5005:5005"
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./project:/var/www/project:cached
      - ./docker/$ENTRY_POINT:/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh:cached
      - ./.m2:/root/.m2
```

**React SignUp method**

```
function SignUp(props) {
  const handleOnSubmit = async (user) => {
    console.log(user);

    await fetch("/api/v1/auth/signup", {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "cors", // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
      cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
      credentials: "same-origin", // include, *same-origin, omit
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(user),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("response", response);
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("data", data);
      });
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <SignUpForm handleOnSubmit={handleOnSubmit} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

**React Vite Config**

```
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    host: true,
    port: 3000,
    cors: true,
    watch: {
      usePolling: true,
    },
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://springbootapp-server:8080/api", 
        # target: url based on docker-compose's spring boot's container_name
        # target: using localhost instead of springbootapp-server causes error 500 and does not reach server
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ""),
      },
    },
  },
});
```

**Spring boot Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/auth", name = "auth")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationController extends BaseController {

    private final AuthenticationServiceImpl authenticationServiceImpl;

    @PostMapping(path = "/signup", name = "signup")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDto> signup(
            @RequestBody SignUpRequest signUpRequest) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(authenticationServiceImpl.signup(signUpRequest));
    }
}
```

**Spring boot Service** # part here I generate the URL

```
String registerToken = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
String confirmationUrl = MvcUriComponentsBuilder
        .fromMethodName(AuthenticationController.class, "confirm", registerToken)
        .build()
        .toString();
```

Expected confirmationURL generated: `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth/confirm/UUIDTOKEN`

Returned confirmationURL generated: `http://springbootapp-server:8080/api/v1/auth/confirm/UUIDTOKEN`